# Runaway script?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

My javascript is set up like -

```
function UpdateLevelRemove() {
  //Do something
    var ajaxCall = $.ajax({ data: { Svc: cntnrRoot,
        Cmd: 'updateLEvel',
        updatePrivacyAction: 'Remove'
    },
        dataType: "text",
        context: this,
        cache: false
    });

    $.when(ajaxCall).then(function () {
        updateLevelRemoveSuccess(recordID)
    });    
}

function updateLevelRemoveSuccess(recordID) {
    //Do something

    __doPostBack('', null);
}
```

I feel like every time I call a function with this structure, my process slows down and I get a "Stop running script?" error.

Am I on the right path or is there something I could add to stop that script? Like handle .done or .always?

Comment: there's probably an infinite loop somewhere in the script

Comment: I've added breakpoints in every function to try to trap that case and none of the breakpoints get hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an infinite loop somewhere in the script

Firebug has a 'break on script running' toggle button that you can click and break on a running script. After breaking just keep stepping through until you find the bug or the loop.

You can also try running the firebug profiler to see which functions are being executed.

Comment: would it have something to do with me calling __doPostBack('', null);?

Comment: ah i googled  __doPostBack and it some special c# thing. You didnt indicate this anywhere in your question which is why i was confused. anyway, i dont know mvc.net and so i cant help you. try doing what i outlined in my answer and you will find the problem yourself